# how to pass same parameter multiple times in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have following index method in ruby

```
def index
  if params.key?(:item)
    @items = Item.get_items.where(item: params[:item])
  else
    @items = Item.get_items
end
```

I am using postman for testing as follows

```
http://localhost:3000/items?item=some_item
```

How can pass same param twice?

e.g

```
http://localhost:3000/items?item=some_item&item=other_item
```

Edit: adding views

index.json.jbuilder

```
json.array! @items, partial: ‘items/item’, as: :item
```

_item.json.jbuilder

```
json.something1 item.something1
json.item_layout do
  json.template_key item.layout
  json.merge! item.layout_config if item.layout_config.present?
end
json.something (item.item_details) do |item_detail|
  json.partial! ‘item_details/item_detail’, item_detail: item_detail
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean, like an array? Try this way

```
http://localhost:3000/items?item[]=some_item&item[]=other_item
```

Comment: Probably worth noting that `?item=some_item&item=other_item` is perfectly valid according to the specs whereas the "this is an array, really it is" `?item[]=some_item&item[]=other_item` version is a convention.

Comment: Oh, do you mean is the same thing? I did not know

Comment: Thanks Ursus. I tried that but i am getting an error at views mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 1 column 13. Any idea why? i added views in question

Comment: Mmmm, it does not seem to have something to do with this question. Are you sure that your `@items` refer to an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object?

Comment: So is the exception raised in `index.json.jbuilder`?

Comment: Sorry man, I suggest you open another question, it seems something different here

Comment: Thanks Ursus. I'll open another question